# Is it bad Perl practice to call binaries such as ls or rm?

Tags: multithreading, perl, process, fork

I find it easy in perl to do things such as:

```
   print "File not found, valid files are:\n\n".`ls DIRECTORY | grep 'php'`;

   `rm -rf directory`

   my @files_list = split("\n", `ls DIRECTORY | grep 'FILE_NAME_REGEX'`)
```

Is it bad practice to do such things?  I find it so much easier to do this than painstakingly implement every thing.  I treat Perl as an advanced version of bash.

Comment: the fact you had to ask should tell you the answer...

Comment: Perl has modules. [Lots of them.](http://www.cpan.org) Make life easier the extensible way (read: without "painstakingly implement[ing]" them).

Comment: One of Perl's motto's is [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) -- "There's more than one way to do it". To me, Perl is a great language to do 'sketches' or 'one-offs' in, but I'm not a Perl programmer by trade. I think the fact that the back-ticks are a shortcut to calling system functions is a good indication that calls like that were intended.

Comment: @transistor1 I disagree.  Sometimes backticks are absolutely required - for example capturing the output of a complicated program - but IMHO they shouldn't be used for operations that are just simple file system or directory operations that Perl excels at.

Comment: @Alnitak - As I said, Perl isn't my primary language; I mainly use it in Cygwin and Linux for one-offs, and not for others' use (probably similarly to what the OP uses it for). I would argue that it depends on what you're building and for whom. However, if shell calls weren't intended to be used regularly in Perl, I doubt Larry Wall et al. would have made them so easy.

Comment: From your question it is clear that your are shelling out just because you don't know Perl properly and are substituting the shell commands that you are familar with. That is just laziness, and you should learn the language

Comment: @transistor1: As Alnitak says, there are very good reasons for shelling out to execute a separate process, but forgetting how to write Perl isn't one of them. It is never a good idea to write in more than one language at a time unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using external binaries is:

1. very inefficient
2. potentially insecure
3. not portable (thx @friedo)
4. lazy...  in most cases there's a Perl module that'll do what you want if you look for it

In this particular case, look at the [`File::Glob`](http://search.cpan.org/~dom/perl-5.12.5/ext/File-Glob/Glob.pm) module.

Comment: @mob: When Larry said that he wasn't talking about negativity - he says *[laziness] makes you write labor-saving programs that other people will find useful, and document what you wrote so you don't have to answer so many questions about it.* That is different from this sort of laziness, which also covers careless indentation and code layout, incomplete testing, non-use of `strict` etc.

Comment: Respectfully disagree. Sometimes it is worthwhile to read and grok the 450 lines of documentation for `File::Path`. Sometimes your time is better spent using the tools you already understand how to use so you have more time to write more labor-saving programs or to write more documentation.

Comment: @mob: I would agree that 'sometimes' you are right about that, but at those same times it is also fine to write ugly, unreadable, undocumented code of all sorts. Go for it

Comment: Bash and ZSH globbing offer a lot more than `File::Glob`. Not that I recommend using shell commands though.

Answer (score 7):

It sort of depends on the expected life of the program. If it's something that you're only going to use yourself, or it's meant as a one-off, it's perfectly fine. That is what it was originally designed for: "Initially designed as a glue language for the UNIX operating system..." (Programming Perl, 2nd Ed. page ix).

On the other hand, if it's a program meant to be used a lot, distributed widely, run on more than one OS, etc. then it's best to use the built-ins and the many packages available via CPAN.

Either way, you should probably always use the unlink function instead of calling out to rm, and the grep or map functions instead of calling out to grep.

Answer (score 5):

And now for a dissenting view. [TMTWOTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it), as @transistor1 said in a comment. And I could also invoke Perl's power of [whipituptitude](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Citations%3amanipulexity). If `cp` and `mv` are more familiar to you than the `File::Copy` module, if you aren't worried about portability, and if your program can afford the performance penalty from starting up an extra process or two (hint: it probably can), Perl makes it easy to integrate these tools into your programs, and there is nothing -- nothing -- wrong with using whatever tools are available to get your task done as quickly as you can.

And heck, sometimes there are those one-off tasks where the Unix utility is the right tool for the job, even when you know how to do the job in Perl.

```
# I need log.err plus the next two oldest and the next two newest 
# files in the current directory. Should I say

chomp(@f = qx[ls -t | grep -C2 log.err]);

# or

@e = sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } glob("*");
($i) = grep { $e[$_] eq 'log.err' } 0..$#e;
@f = @e[$i-2 .. $i+2];

# or

use Acme::OlderNewer::FileFinder;
@f = find_oldernewer_files(".", "log.err", -2, +2);

# ?  Or suppose I want a list of all the *.pm files under all 
# directories in @INC, and we lucked out so that nothing in @INC
# has any spaces or special characters. 
# Is my script any less useful for saying

chomp(@f = `find @INC -name \\*.pm`);

# than

use File::Find;
find( sub { /\.pm$/ && push @f, $File::Find::name }, @INC );
```

Comment: Just a guess, but I doubt if you would consider calling `system` in C to do such file operations? I wonder why?

Comment: In C? But I thought we weren't supposed to be programming in more than one language at a time?! ;)

Comment: I sure as heck would consider it. I know exactly what `system("rm -r my_directory")` is going to do. Of course that can be done in C (the `rm` program is surely written in C), but how much effort will it take me to find out what the right system calls are? Maybe not much. How much effort is it worth if I already know how to do exactly what I want in a second-best way? Maybe not much.

Comment: @mob: Then you write code the likes of which I have never seen in thirty years. You are an island!

Comment: Understood. If a characteristic of your program is "I might show this code to someone else", then that is an argument in favor of a first-best solution.

Answer (score 4):

Using backticks is usually slower and somewhat insecure, and depending on the action you want, perl is not more difficult, you just have to know what to do. For example:

```
print "File not found, valid files are\n\n", grep /php/, glob 'DIRECTORY/*';
unlink glob 'directory/*'; 
rmdir 'directory';
my @files = grep /REGEX/, glob 'DIRECTORY/*';
```

Perl is built to accomodate the lazy, but most of the normal things you do with bash you can easily do in perl. Not learning how to do it is your call, but I would think if you do it a lot it would make things easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

As with most engineering questions, the answer is "That depends.".

Treating Perl as a scripting language sacrifices portability, maintainability, execution speed, and other properties for getting the task before you accomplished in minimum time.  The consequences of making those sacrifices are not constant, but are rather a function of the complexity of your program.  The more complex your program, the more likely you are to pay more in terms of maintainability than you gain in whipitupitude, and the more likely you would be making a bad choice by shelling out.

There is no universally right answer here.  In some cases, you need a script to work once.  In others, you need it to work a few times, but it's short.  And in others, you are writing an application of tens of thousands of lines across hundreds of source files.  The scenario in which it is used dictates which tool is most appropriate, not some sort of perfect rule.

Sometimes, you'll see this approach derided as "laziness".  And that's what it is.  Whether you take the above into consideration and retain a willingness to change your approach when your parameters change determines whether you are engaging in the good kind of laziness or the bad kind of laziness.  The truly lazy person knows that sometimes the laziest thing to do is to start over.